# delphi firemoneky controls at runtime

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm creating FMX controls on the fly at runtime to edit data within a ListBox:

[image: Screenshot here]

It is working fine for most components, except for `TComboTrackBar` and `TSpinBox`, for which no value is displayed despite the following code.

Here for the SpinBox:

```
// Create the SpinBox
SpinBox:= TSpinBox.Create(InternalLayout);
With SpinBox do
begin
  Parent:= InternalLayout;
  Name:= 'sb' + ASubParameter.Name;
  BeginUpdate;
    Align:= TAlignLayout.Client;
    Size.PlatformDefault:= False;
    HitTest:= True;
    Margins.Top:= 1;
    Margins.Bottom:= 1;
    Min:= ASubParameter.Minimum;
    Max:= ASubParameter.Maximum;
    DecimalDigits:= 3;
    KeyboardType:=  TVirtualKeyboardType.NumberPad;
    case AParameter.ParamType of
      TParameterType.ptShortInt, TParameterType.ptInteger:
        begin
          ValueType:= TNumValueType.Integer;
          Value:= ASubParameter.ValueDefault.ToInteger;
        end;
      TParameterType.ptSingle, TParameterType.ptDouble:
        begin
          ValueType:= TNumValueType.Float;
          Value:= ASubParameter.ValueDefault.ToSingle;
        end;
      end;
    Enabled:= not(ASubParameter.ReadOnly);
    OnChange:=  ASubParameter.OnChanged;
  EndUpdate;
end;
```

In this case, all SpinBoxes are supposed to display 0 as the default value.
If I tap the right arrow, I get 1. If I then tap the left arrow, I get 0.
So the behaviour is correct, but the controls don't display the starting value correctly.

Any idea what could be wrong or missing in my code?

On Windows, this works OK. On Android, this does not work OK.

Comment: What Delphi version do you use? It works for me on Android on Delphi 10.2.1

Comment: Also what style do you use? It does not look like one of standard ones, so maybe it does not support spinbox properly

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestion. I have tried without the StyleBook and it has the same result. Value is not displayed until I'm using the GUI to change the vale. This is the same for Trackbar and SPinBox.

Comment: By the way. I'm using 10.1 Berlin as I have other problems with 10.2

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in 10.2, in 10.1 looks like 0 is special value, what worked for me is assign it to some other value first, e.g.

```
SpinBox.Value := 1;
SpinBox.Value := 0;
```

in this case value shows up